# Cant get information of my friends - Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to get information of my friends, but just return of some friends, not all.

What is the problem?

Comment: Problem is you no read documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In v2.0 of the Graph API is not possible to do that.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u).